# Implementing Voice Over for iPhone application

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, voiceover

I need to support Voice Over (for blind/partial blind persons) for my application. Please guide me how to implement this feature.

Comment: Isn't voice over for *blind* people?

Comment: @Magnus Not sure what you say here. Of course Voice Over is useful for any kind of lowered ability of vision. And I know lots of blind people use the iPhone with Voice Over alone. Braille is as well - it needs more hardware though. BTW, I was commenting on the fact that Abhinav was mentioning hearing disabled people and not visually impaired.

Comment: @Magnus : VoiceOver is not only used by sight-impaired people (including blind people) but also by many illiterate people as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the [Accessibility Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Accessibility_on_iPhone/Accessibility_on_iPhone.html) .

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is very vague with many aspects, so I'll try to touch a few:

Technically, if you can abstract each string from the interface, this can help: http://www.acapela-for-iphone.com/. From the top of my head, I can think of saying out loud the positions of the interface elements. This approach requires simple interfaces, with few elements on 1 screen and maybe multiple screens for subsequent actions.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I've seen so far is this article which points to a Stanford lecture by Apple Engineer, Chris Fleisach

http://www.podfeet.com/blog/tutorials-5/build-accessible-ios-apps/

Chris's video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5b0V6MltEnw

The video has what we all are looking for.

In the video starting around the 15:30 sec mark Chris starts talking about the relevant information.  The API discussion starts at 19:29 sec.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to take a look at :

- The [design criteria](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/criteria-ios.html) to be well known before you code.
- The [developers guide](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html) to get some info about the way to code essential features.
- The [VoiceOver gestures](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/voiceover.html) if you need to know more than just the basic ones.
- Some [WWDC videos](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc.html) that are summarized and perfectly detailed with video timelapses to get directly the appropriate playback.

Many illustrations help to understand the concepts and the code snippets are provided in ObjC and Swift.